# Return Title from Header in section from the array that is dynamic

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a array like this:

```
 var PropertiesForSectionFromModel :[String] = [String]()
```

and mapped the array to this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadData()
   }
 func loadData()
 {   //Here is a Api call and i have successfully called it.
     self.PropertiesForSectionFromModel = Array(self.DataSource.map({
            (item) -> String in item.labelText
            }))
             self.tableView.reloadData()

            print(self.PropertiesForSectionFromModel)

        }

    }

}
```

here i get the print(self.PropertiesForSectionFromModel)
["First Name", "last Name", "Date of Birth", "Email"]. Here are four items so now it should have four sections. These sections are dynamic in nature. it can have many more sections according to the items in **PropertiesForSectionFromModel**

Now i want to set them as a titleForHeaderInSection. I have done like this:
`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.PropertiesForSectionFromModel[section]

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.PropertiesForSectionFromModel.count
    }
```

` but the title is not being displayed..Can anybody help me why it is not displaying..??

Comment: are you working on swift 3?

Comment: no its 2 not 3.

Comment: Can you debug and check what count value you are getting in numberOfSectionsInTableView?

Comment: each section will have only one row

Comment: I agree with @TusharSharma, try to print the count to see if the array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // return the height of the header, e.g. 50.0
    return 50.0
}
```

Comment: still nothing is displayed in heading

Comment: Did you reload the tableview after `PropertiesForSectionFromModel` has entries?

Comment: i haven/t set the cells just want to set sections